# CNOT Gate on Entangled Qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, quantum-state

I was trying to generate Greenberger-Horne-Zeilinger (GHZ) state for $N$ states using quantum computing, starting with $|000...000\rangle$ (N times)

The proposed solution is to first apply Hadamard Transformation on the first qubit, and then start a loop of CNOT gates with the first qubit of all the others.

I am unable to understand how I can perform CNOT($q_1,q_2$) if $q_1$ is a part of an entangled pair, like the Bell state $B_0$ which forms here after the Hadamard transformation.

I know how to write the code for it, but algebraically why is this method correct and how is it done? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am unable to understand how I can perform CNOT($q_1,q_2$) if $q_1$
>   is a part of an entangled pair, like the Bell state $B_0$ which forms
>   here after the Hadamard transformation.

The key is to notice what happens to the **computational basis states** (or, for that matter, any other *complete* set of basis states) upon applying the relevant quantum gate(s). Doesn't matter whether the state is entangled or separable. This method *always* works.

Let's consider the $2$-qubit Bell state (of two qubits $A$ and $B$):

$$|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$$

$|\Psi\rangle$ is formed by an equal **linear** superposition of the computational basis states $|00\rangle$ & $|11\rangle$ (which can be expressed as $|0\rangle_A\otimes|0\rangle_B$ and $|1\rangle_A\otimes|1\rangle_B$ respectively) and $|1\rangle_A\otimes |1\rangle_B$. We need not worry about the other two computational basis states: $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ as they are not part of the Bell state superposition $|\Psi\rangle$. A CNOT gate basically **flips** (i.e. does either one of the two mappings $|0\rangle \mapsto |1\rangle$ or $|1\rangle\mapsto |0\rangle$) the state of the qubit $B$ **in case** the qubit $A$ is in the state $|1\rangle$, or else it does nothing at all.

So basically CNOT will keep the computational basis state $|00\rangle$ as it is. However, it will convert the computational basis state $|11\rangle$ to $|10\rangle$. From the action of CNOT on $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$, you can deduce the action of CNOT on the superposition state $|\Psi\rangle$ now:

$$\operatorname{CNOT}|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |10\rangle)$$

---

**Edit**:

You mention in the comments that you want one of the two qubits of the entangled state $|\Psi\rangle$ to act as **control** (and the NOT operation will be applied on a different qubit, *say* $C$, *depending upon the control*).

In that case too, you can proceed in a similar way as above.

Write down the **$3$-qubit combined state**:

$$|\Psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle_C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_A\otimes |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A\otimes|1\rangle_B)\otimes |0\rangle_C$$ $$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_A\otimes |0\rangle_B\otimes |0\rangle_C+ |1\rangle_A\otimes|1\rangle_B\otimes|0\rangle_C)$$

Let's say $B$ is your **control** qubit.

Once again we will simply check the action of the CNOT on the computational basis states (for a 3-qubit system) i.e. $|000\rangle$ & $|110\rangle$. In computational basis state $|000\rangle = |0\rangle_A\otimes|0\rangle_B|0\rangle_C$ notice that the state of the qubit $B$ is $|0\rangle$ and that of qubit $C$ is $|0\rangle$. Since qubit $B$ is in state $|0\rangle$, the state of qubit $C$ will **not** be flipped. However, notice that in the computational basis state $|110\rangle = |1\rangle_A\otimes|1\rangle_B\otimes|0\rangle_C$ the qubit $B$ is in state $|1\rangle$ while qubit $C$ is in state $|0\rangle$. Since the qubit $B$ is in state $|1\rangle$, the state of the qubit $C$ will be flipped to $|1\rangle$.

Thus, you end up with the state:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_A\otimes|0\rangle_B\otimes|0\rangle_C + |1\rangle_A\otimes|1\rangle_B\otimes|1\rangle_C)$$

This is *the* [Greenberger–Horne–Zeilinger state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state) for your $3$ qubits!

Comment: We can use this method if we want to apply CNOT on an entangled pair. But I don't want to do that. What I want is, to take the first qubit of the entangled state $B_0$ (can't call it q1 as it is inseparable) , and apply CNOT on that (q1) and a different $|0>$ qubit. If possible please show the matrix form multiplication done. Thanks again.

Comment: @SatvikGolechha So which one are you considering to be the **control** qubit (of the controlled-NOT gate): $q1$ or the "different $|0\rangle$ qubit"? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: I am considering $q1$ to be the control bit. And the difficulty I'm facing is that I can't separate $q1$, and hence can't see what the CNOT gate will do to $q1$ and $|0>$.

Comment: @SatvikGolechha Updated the answer. OK now?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Using Tensor product properties makes it all very clear, and it just fits in beautifully now. I've marked this answer as accepted.

Comment: @SatvikGolechha Glad it helped! Welcome to the site :). By the way, please check out the short [MathJax tutorial](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/50/26) here. It will help you in formatting mathematical expressions, especially the bra-ket notation. Don't use `$|0>$`. Use `$|0\rangle$` instead!

Comment: I'll make sure the next time. I am fluent with LaTeX and so MathJax will be easy to  learn I guess. Thanks again @Blue You're great!

Comment: Can this be inferred that for the first two qubits, they are in entanglement with respect two qubit world, but not in 3-qubit world. when we add cnot on third gate(and control on q1), then the system becomes entangle din 3-qubit world?

Answer (score 7):

$$
\psi_1 = |0 0 0 \rangle\\
\psi_2 = (H \otimes I \otimes I) \psi_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0 \rangle + |1 \rangle) \otimes |0 0 \rangle\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |0 0 0 \rangle + |1 0 0 \rangle)\\
\psi_3 = (\operatorname{CNOT}_{12} \otimes I) \psi_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0 0 0 \rangle + |1 1 0 \rangle)\\
\psi_4 = (\operatorname{CNOT}_{13} \otimes I_{2}) \psi_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0 0 0 \rangle + |1 1 1 \rangle)\\
$$

$\operatorname{CNOT}_{ij}$ is itself an operator on $2$ qubits giving a $4\times 4$ unitary matrix. You can apply it to any state in $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$ not just those of the form $q_i \otimes q_j$. Just write the coefficients in the computational basis where you know what to do in terms of the $\operatorname{CNOT}_{ij}$ of classical reversible computing. Then just follow your linearity nose.